# use of distainer office, distrainment proceedings, etc

Tags: word-choice, legalese

Is "distainer office, distrainment proceedings, distrain order, ..." correct? Even this spell checker highlights these words as incorrect.
Some translations use execution office, executor's office, etc., which I don't find correct.
I would also appreciate some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Computer spellcheckers are notoriously stupid beyond all belief.  Almost all instances of this type of question are readily answered  simply by consulting a decent dictionary.

Per the OED, ***distrainment*** is:

> The action or fact of distraining; distraint.

Which probably doesn’t help much.  The noun ***distrain*** is obsolete, and means per the OED either:

> 1. = **distraint**.
> 2. Restraint, control.

The noun ***distraint*** is not marked obsolete, but I would not expect it outside of legal contexts:

> ### distraint `/dɪˈstreɪnt/`.
>
> Etymology: f. distrain *v.*, perh. after OFr. *destrainte* (13–16th c. in Godef.), *destraincte* ‘a restraint of libertie’ (Cotgr.), fem. sb. from pa. pple.: cf. constraint.
>
> The action of distraining (in the legal sense); = **distress** *sb.* <sup>**3**</sup>.
>
> - 1730–6 in Bailey (folio).
> - 1833 Ht. Martineau *Loom & Lugger* i. vii. 115 ― There would be a distraint for penalties.
> - 1869 *Daily News* 25 Aug., ― The bailiffs shortly afterwards entered the house, and··made a distraint which almost stripped it of furniture. * 1874 Green *Short Hist.* viii. §10. 571 ― Payment of taxes··was enforced by distraint.
> - 1875 Maine *Hist. Inst.* ix. 262 ― The distraint of cattle for damages still retains a variety of archaic features.
>
> **b.** ***distraint of knighthood***: compulsion to accept knighthood (in consequence of tenure of a knight’s fee, or an estate worth £20 a year). (See distrain *v.* <sup>**7**</sup> <sup>**b**</sup>, quot. **1647**.)
>
> - 1875 Stubbs *Const. Hist.* II. xv. 281 ― The distraint of knighthood was··a link between the two branches of the national force.

As a verb, ***distrain*** is for the most part obsolete in modern English outside legal contexts.  Here is a **very** abbreviated entry from the OED for it. Please see the examples for the alternatives, depending on your intent.

> ### distrain `/dɪˈstreɪn/`, *v.*
>
> Forms: **3–6** **destreyn(e**, **4–6** **des-**, **distrayne**, **distreyne**, (**4** **-trene**, **4–5** **dystreyne**, **5** **-trayne**, **6** **-treine**), **5–8** **distrein**, **6–7** **distraine**, **6–** **distrain**; *Sc.* **4–7** **des-**, **dys-**, **distrenȝe**, **-trinȝe**.
>
> Etymology: ME. a. OFr. *destreindre*, *-aindre* ‘to straine, presse, wring, vexe extremely, straiten’ (Cotgr.), pres. stem *destreign-*, pa. pple. *destreint*; = Ital. *distrignere*, *-stringere* ‘to distraine, distress, pinch, straiten’ (Florio) :– L. *distring-ĕre* to draw asunder, stretch out, detain, occupy, f. *dī-*, **dis-** <sup>**1**</sup> + *stringĕre* to squeeze, draw tight. In med.L. and Romanic, the prefix lost its sundering force, being prob. confounded with *de-*, and *distringĕre* became merely intensive of *stringĕre*, as in mod.Ital.
>
> **I.** General senses: all *Obs.*
>
> [...]
>
> **II.** *Law*. The earliest use recorded, but etymologically a specific application of 4.
>
> † **7.** *trans.* **a.** To constrain or force (a person) by the seizure and detention of a chattel or thing, to perform some obligation (as to pay money owed by him, to make satisfaction for some wrong done by him or by his beasts, or to perform some other act, e.g. to appear in court); to punish by such seizure and detention for the non-performance of such obligation. (See **distress** *sb.* <sup>**II**</sup>.) *Obs.* exc. *Hist.*
>   , or as included in c.
>
> - C. 1290 *Beket* 758 in *S. Eng. Leg.* I. 128 ― Non Erchebishop of Caunturburi nas neuere i-somoned so, Ne so destreyned of no king [*v.r*. of nothing].
> - 1292 **Britton i.** xxvii. [xxvi]. §1 ― Le viscounte face destreyndre les trespasours par lour avers et par lour chateus.
> - 1414 *Coldingham Papers* (1841) 86 ― Full power and autorite··the same tenantz and tenantdris til distreyn and hald, till all rerages and dettes··be assethid.
> - 1512 *Act 4 Hen. VIII*, c. 19 §9 ― For none payment therof to destreyn the seid persones so beyng behynde by their goodes and catalles.
> - 1568 **Grafton** *Chron.* II. 142 ― To make sommons, and distreyne for lacke of appearaunce, all and every Tenant of the sayd Abbot.
> - 1671 **F. Phillips** *Reg. Necess.* 467 ― He refused to give leave··to distrein the Bishop of St. Davids in Parliament time.
> - 1895 **Pollock** & **Maitland** *Hist. Eng. Law* I. 335 ― After distraining the tenant by his chattels, the lord may obtain from his seignorial tribunal a judgment authorizing him to distrain the tenant by his land.
> - 1895 **Pollock** & **Maitland** *Hist. Eng. Law* II. 574 ― Observe that [in the 13th c.], when words are correctly used, one does not distrain a thing; one distrains a man by (*per*) a thing.
>
> **b.** with *inf.* or *subord*. *clause*, expressing the purpose.
>
> - C. 1290 *Beket* 748 in *S. Eng. Leg.* I. 128 ― Seint thomas londes into is hond his men nome, Ase it were for-to destreynen him þat he to his court come.
> - C. 1315 **Shoreham** 72 ― Destrayned be he scholde, Be rytte To do hyt ȝyf that he may.
> - 1609 **Skene** *Reg. Maj.* 27 ― He may be distrenzied in his lands, to come to court.
> - A. 1626 **Bacon** *Max. & Uses Com. Law* (1636) 20 ― Commanding him [the Sheriffe] to distraine them by their lands to appear at a certaine day.
> - 1641 *Art. agst. Sir H. Davenport* in Rushw. *Hist. Coll.* **iii.** (1692) I. 335 ― That he should distrain James Maleverer, Esq; to appear before the Barons of his Majesty’s said Court of Exchequer.
> - 1647 **N. Bacon** *Disc. Govt. Eng.* **i.** lxx. (1739) 184 ― All such as ought to be Knights and are not, shall be distrained to undertake the weapons of Knighthood.
> - 1767 **Blackstone** *Comm.* II. 135 ― The widow shall pay nothing for her marriage, nor shall be distreined to marry afresh.
> - 1895 **Pollock** & **Maitland** *Hist. Eng. Law* I. 334 ― The lord’s handiest remedy is that of distraining his tenant to perform the services that are in arrear.
>
> **c.** In later usage: To levy a distress upon (a person), in order by the sale of the chattels to obtain satisfaction for a debt, particularly for arrears of rent. (But the usual construction in this sense is *to distrain upon*: see <sup>**8**</sup> <sup>**b**</sup>.)
>
> - 1768–74 **Tucker** *Lt. Nat.* **i.** ii. §9 ― When Squire Peremptory distrained his tenant for rent perhaps he [etc.].
> - 1772 *Hist. Rochester* 46 ― Who had been distrained for the repair of the head of the bridge.
> - 1818 **Cruise** *Digest* (ed. 2) III. 201 ― A peer of the realm could never be arrested for debt; the law presuming that he had sufficient lands and tenements in which he might be distrained.
>
> **8.** *absol.* or *intr.* To levy a distress. Const. *for* (a thing). Originally in order to compel the defaulter, by detention of the thing seized, to pay money due or perform an obligation; but in later use inclu
>   ding the power to obtain satisfaction by sale of the chattels. See **distress** *sb.* <sup>**3**</sup>.
>
> - C. 1350 in *Eng. Gilds* (1870) 362 ― Ȝif eny þo þat nymeþ rente of eny tenement in fraunchyse of þe Citee, and his rente holleche be by-hynde, oþer half oþer more and he ne fynde for to dystreyne.
> - 1463 *Bury Wills* (Camden) 27 ― If my wil be nat devly executyd in eche part, they to haue pover to distreyne.
> - 1512 **Fabyan** *Will* in *Chron.* Pref. 9, ― I geve full power over the said Church Wardeyns··to distreyn within any of the foresaid londs and tenements··and the distres so taken to withold and kepe till the said annuyti
>     e··be fully contented and paied.
> - 1512 *Act 4 Hen. VIII*, c. 11 ― To distreyne for the same rentes in the seid Maners.
> - 1552 in *Vicary’s Anat.* (1888) App. iii. 152 ― It shalbe laufull for any offycer of the said Cytie to dystreine for the same [yearly rent].
> - 1648 **Milton** *Observ. Art. Peace* Wks. 1738 I. 338 ― Any seven or more of them, in case of Refractories or Delinquency, may distrain and imprison.
> - 1764 **Burn** *Poor Laws* 251 ― Where power is given to distrain, it seemeth reasonable that power should be given to come at the goods.
> - 1863 **Fawcett** *Pol. Econ.* **ii.** vii. 237 ― The landlord had of course a legal right to distrain for the rent.
>
> **b.** Const. *upon*, *on* a person or thing. (With indirect passive *to be distrained upon*.)
>
> - 1605 **Camden** *Rem.* (J.), ― I will not lend money to my superiour, upon whom I cannot distrain for the debt.
> - 1689 *Col. Rec. Pennsylv.* I. 311 ― He was distreyned upon by Cornelius Empson, for Contrey Rates.
> - 1812 *Examiner* 7 Sept. 570/2 ― He was··threatened··to be distrained on for the assessment and surcharge.
> - 1861 **Pearson** *Early & Mid. Ages Eng.* xxxiv. (L.), ― He or his heirs might distrain on them if this were neglected.

Unless you are reading laws written several hundred years ago, I would not expect to encounter these words, and I certainly would not use them unless a lawyer made me do so.

Comment: Thanks for lengthy and detailed explanation. It is very useful. Nevertheless I see no reference how the related office and officer is called, such as distraint office, distrainer or distrainor, etc. Or which expression/collocation is currently used for such office/job. I hope you received some credits after I voted.

Comment: It's OK what you say but what to use instead.

Comment: @Miki you missed the example with the _bailiff_ related to distraint.